# MVC 4 json via ajax not working?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, json, ajax

so I'm making a Cascading DropDownList and here's my Codes,

Controller :

```
    public JsonResult GetStates(string id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> ListOfStates = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var TempSlist = this.GetStateList(Convert.ToInt32(id));
        var StateData = TempSlist.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.SName,
                Value= m.SID.ToString(),
            });

        return Json(StateData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public IList<StateList> GetStateList(int CID)
    {
        GetCSCTContext DB = new GetCSCTContext();

        return DB.StateLists.Where(m => m.CID_FK == CID).ToList();
    }


}
```

and for

View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#StatesDDL").hide();
            $('#CntryDDL').change(function () {
                $('#StatesDDL').show();

            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetStates", "Register")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data :
                    {
                        id: $('#CntryDDL').val()
                    },
                success: function (states)
                {
                    alert(CID);
                    $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                        $('#StatesDDL').append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">'
                            + state.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                },
            });
```

I've been trying to make this ajax part work, but I don't see any errors via browser and when I try to do breakpoint in my controller, it seems that it's not triggering the function in the controller.

Comment: Is it a POST call or GET call?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the ajax call not triggering while debugging. So either you may write:

`GET` method instead of `POST` as your controller function also take the argument as get parameter.

```
public JsonResult GetStates(string id) // get -> string id
```

OR you may like:

```
public JsonResult GetStates(){
   string id = Request.Params["id"]
    ........
}
```